# how to set the __block_editor_compatible_meta_box parameter to false?

Tags: wordpress, smartling

I am trying to install and activate the smartling connector plugin. I installed the smartling plugin and MultilingualPress plugin as a Network admin.

Then, I got the following error

```
WARNING: MultilingualPress 2 is not compatible with Gutenberg. BEFORE you update your WordPress to version 5.0 please read our [MultilingualPress and WordPress 5.0 guide][1]
```

I went to that above-mentioned guide, there they mentioned to set 
`__block_editor_compatible_meta_box parameter to false` like following:

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box', 'My Meta Box', 'my_meta_box_callback',
    null, 'normal', 'high',
    array(
        '__block_editor_compatible_meta_box' => false,
    )
);
```

but am not sure, In which file I need to add this code. Could someone help me to solve this issue?

I have tried to install a disable Guntenberg plugin. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mention is best suited for a custom plugin file. I would suggest creating a plugin just for that, so you don't touch your theme's functions.php (which is another place you can put it). You can refer to the [basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/) on creating one. The code you provide needs to be wrapped in a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/) for adding metaboxes. You can read more about hooks and actions in the basics link above.

Essentially all you need to do is add a PHP file to your `wp-content/plugins/` folder. I would name it mpupgrade.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: MP Upgrade plugin
 */

function mpupgrade_add_meta()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'my-meta-box',
        'My Meta Box',
        'my_meta_box_callback',
        null,
        'normal',
        'high',
        array(
            '__block_editor_compatible_meta_box' => false,
        )
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'mpupgrade_add_meta');
```

After saving that file, you need to go to wp-admin->Plugins and activate this plugin. That's it.